# Execute program over webpage (like Steam)

Tags: c++, html

I am trying to execute a program I have programed on my PC in C++. I dont want to use it like a virus or malware.

But I saw this on Steam, if you want to download a game, the webpage asks you to open Steam, and if you click ok it executes Steam!

Could someone give me a code or something ?

Comment: Don't have steam, but most likely this is doing what most programs do; they register a protocol (like `irc://` or `ftp://`) then specify the application to handle that protocol. ([msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: I believe this is the same as launching itunes etc.. and that the href protocol is registered with the application. i.e itunes is `itms://`

Comment: @BradChristie you are correct it uses `steam://`

Comment: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx

In other words, you need to have the application installed first, and then you can receive requests from browsers that start with that protocol.

On Windows, protocols are stored in Windows registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. Just have a look at the `http` key etc., that's where the default browser application is referenced, for example (that's what that "Do you want to make Chrome your default browser?" dialog sets).

Note that this will always start a new process when you click on a link, so if you only want the message to get to an already open application, you have to have some startup logic that finds out if another instance is already running, then sending the message and shutting down.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now !

Answer (score 2):

So, assuming you want to register `myscheme://` to your application which was located at `C:\Program Files\My Application\MyApplication.exe`:

First, create a registry file that creates this new scheme and hands it off to your application for processing.

**demo.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myscheme]
@="URL:MyApplication Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myscheme\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\Program Files\My Application\MyApplication.exe,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myscheme\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myscheme\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myscheme\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\Program Files\My Application\MyApplication.exe\" \"%1\""
```

*Something like that, though never tested and proofed it*

Then, you update your application to handle the incoming request. So, for example a link with:

```
<a href="myscheme://foo">Click Me!</a>
```

Would then be passed off to your application with a call that resembled:

```
"C:\program Files\My Application\MyApplication.exe" "myscheme://foo"
```

So, update your application to handle this incoming request, then perform whatever action(s) you want once it receives the hand-off.

*Follow-Up*

Ideally the above would all be automated. For instance, at time of installation you would add the registry keys using the installed folder location. But, for the sake of simplicity and demo, I've made it a .reg file you can use to test with.

Also, you can play with the default value in the `command` key and add another argument to make processing the incoming request easier. e.g. instad of just passing `"%1"` you could supply `-uri "%1"` then within `char*[] args` look for `-uri` and process the next arg as the incoming request. this is entirely your call.